# Как добавить в xcode такую панель?

Tags: ios, xcode

Обновил Xcode и пропала панель для добавления view(изображение ниже). Куда нажать, чтобы она появилась??[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она не пропала, теперь это отдельный элемент. Нажать в правом верхнем углу на первую кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]